# 4D chaotic system Lyapunov exponent

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ode, chaos

I am trying to work on the 4 dimensional chaotic attractor Lyapunov spectrum and there values so far the code mention below works well for three dimensional system but errors arise in 4D and 5D system

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def diff_Lorenz(u):
    x,y,z,w= u
    f = [a*(y-x) , x*z+w, b-x*y, z*y-c*w]
    Df = [[-a,a,0,0], [z,0, x,1], [-y, -x, 0,0],[0,z,y,-c]]
    return np.array(f), np.array(Df)


def LEC_system(u):
    #x,y,z = u[:3]
    U = u[2:18].reshape([4,4])
    L = u[12:15]
    f,Df = diff_Lorenz(u[:4])
    A = U.T.dot(Df.dot(U))
    dL = np.diag(A).copy();
    for i in range(4):
        A[i,i] = 0
        for j in range(i+1,4): A[i,j] = -A[j,i]
    dU = U.dot(A)
    return np.concatenate([f,dU.flatten(),dL])


a=6;b=11;c=5;

u0 = np.ones(4)
U0 = np.identity(4)
L0 = np.zeros(4)
u0 = np.concatenate([u0, U0.flatten(), L0])
t = np.linspace(0,10,301)
u = odeint(lambda u,t:LEC_system(u),u0,t, hmax=0.05)
L = u[5:,12:15].T/t[5:]

# plt.plot(t[5:],L.T) 
# plt.show()
p1=L[0,:];p2=L[1,:];p3=L[2,:];p4=L[3,:]
L1 = np.mean(L[0,:]);L2=np.average(L[1,:]);L3=np.average(L[2,:]);L4=np.average(L[3,:])
t1 = np.linspace(0,100,len(p1))
plt.plot(t1,p1);plt.plot(t1,p2);plt.plot(t1,p3);plt.plot(t1,p4)

# plt.show()
print('LES= ',L1,L2,L3,L4)
```

**the output error is**

```py
D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py:247: ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
  warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7008/1971199288.py in <module>
     32 # plt.plot(t[5:],L.T)
     33 # plt.show()
---> 34 p1=L[0,:];p2=L[1,:];p3=L[2,:];p4=L[3,:]
     35 L1=np.mean(L[0,:]);L2=np.average(L[1,:]);L3=np.average(L[2,:]);L4=np.average(L[3,:])
     36 t1 = np.linspace(0,100,len(p1))

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

what is wrong?

**output expected is**
*L1=.5162,L2=-.0001,L3=-4.9208,L4=-6.5954*

Comment: The derivative of the last equation should be `[y,x,0,-c]`. Or is the equation wrong?

Comment: My bad. But still it's not working

Comment: upadated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LEC_system(u)`, the flat vector `u` contains in sequence

- the state vector, `n` components,
- the eigenbasis `U`, a `n x n` matrix
- the accumulated exponents `L`, `n` components.

With `n=4`, this translates thus to the decomposition

```
def LEC_system(u):
    #x,y,z,w = u[:4]
    U = u[4:20].reshape([4,4])
    L = u[20:24]
    f,Df = diff_Lorenz(u[:4])
    A = U.T.dot(Df.dot(U))
    dL = np.diag(A).copy();
    for i in range(4):
        A[i,i] = 0
        for j in range(i+1,4): A[i,j] = -A[j,i]
    dU = U.dot(A)
    return np.concatenate([f,dU.flatten(),dL])
```

Of course, in the evaluation after the integration one has to likewise use the correct segment of the state vector

```
L = u[5:,20:24].T/t[5:]
```

Then I get the plot
[image]

and only using the latter quart of the graphs, after integrating to `t=60`

```
LES=  0.029214865425355396 -0.43816854013111833 -4.309199339754925 -6.28183676249535
```

This still are not the expected values, as that appears to be contracting along all directions transversal to the solution curve.

Comment: waooo.. plz explain     U = u[4:20].reshape([4,4])
    L = u[20:24]

Comment: The `u` vector is split at (before) the positions `0, n, n+n*n, n+n*n+n`, the outer positions are not splits. For `n=4` the values `0, 4, 20, 24` result.

Comment: what if the system has 5D then ... 0 , n, n+n*n , n+n*n+n, then ?

Comment: Yes, the pattern remains the same, then with the component separations before index `0, 5, 30, 35`.

Comment: what about this? U = u[4:20] how u get this solved?

Comment: for 5D this willbe like this............. U = u[5:30].reshape([5,5])
    L = u[30:35]??

Comment: Yes, exactly. The sub-array needs to be reformatted into a matrix.

Comment: thanks alot ..plz also help me in drawing basin of attractions for different dynamical systems.. if u say ill post a full question for this new query as well..

Comment: Basins of attraction or Fatou sets only work if you have multiple stable fixed/stationary/equilibrium points. Limit cycles or strange attractors work too, but the multiplicity of them is crucial, else you get no differentiation. Another visualization of dynamical systems is the Poincaré section. So if you ask a new question on that, find a sensible example and explain what you expect to see. If it is not a coding problem, the question will likely off-topic here, math.SE or scicomp.SE could be more appropriate.

Comment: u = odeint(lambda u,t:LEC_system(u),u0,t, hmax=0.05)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 241, in odeint
    output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: for 5 by 5 matrix its giving me this error

Comment: given:
    f = [ y - x +  y*z + u + a ,-y + 3*x*z + b,-3*x*y + w,- x + d,-2*x  - c*y]
    Df = [[-1,1+z,y,0,1], [3*z,-1,3*x,0,0], [-3*y,-3*x,0,1,0],[-1,0,0,0,0],[-2,-c,0,0,0]] where; a = 0;b = 1; c = 2; d = -0.01

Comment: Do a search for this error "TypeError ..." for similar cases, it happens often enough. You are passing a structured object, like an array, where a scalar is expected. I can not see from the provided code where this happens

Comment: Lehmann I posted the new code above as an answer. See there what is the problem!

Comment: Please do not do that, open a new question for a new problem, while performing all the usual debugging required. One elementary step is to try the code from a fresh workspace (refresh kernel, or copy into empty), or run the script from the command line. Then you would get the different error "name 'a' is not defined", or in your case, it was defined with some unrelated content, at least in the case of `d`.

Comment: The fifth scalar variable is `t`, `u` is still the array of all components.

Comment: changes have made .. still the type error persist .. i think i need to post this question again

Comment: Did you remove the `u` from the first component of `f`?

Comment: myy baaadddd.............. its working :D thanks aloooot